# flex: how to know preloader progress?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I know that preloader is the first piece downloaded and it will load the large part of the swf. I want to know the progress of the large part downloading, and for simplicity I don't need UI to display the percentage, the data will be passed to HTML, HTML will handle the UI.

Is there any easy way to get the preloader event in flex? Without adding a lot of code in flex?

Thanks.

Comment: This is sort of more Flash than flex framework stuff, the Flash SystemManager class loads the Preloader then begins loading the Application and passes events along to the Preloader.  You can have Flex/Flash spit out messages when the PROGRESS_EVENT fires on the loader that the system manger is using to load the application then pass the bytesLoaded and bytesTotal through to Javascript using ExternalInterface... if it isn't obvious this isn't a completely trivial task the information isn't exposed as part of the framework or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend the download progress bar class and use it instead of the default. You can get the progress of the download then. Good example [here](http://jessewarden.com/2007/07/making-a-cooler-preloader-in-flex-part-1-of-3.html)